# Уникальный рандомный звук

Tags: javascript

нужно воспроизвести уникальные звуки из рандомного массива. делаю так: создала массив звуков и рандом для них, так же есть массив индекса звуков. то есть, цикл должен брать рандомный звук под индексом N-ым его воспроизводить и удалять элемент индекса звуков из массива. пока у меня так:

```js
function(play) {
  let sound = ["sound1.mp3", "sound2.mp3", "sound3.mp3"];
  let arr = [3, 1, 2];
  let ranWords = Math.floor(Math.random() * sound.length);
  let audio = new Audio(sound[ranWords]);
  audio.play();

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let a = new Audio(audio[arr[i] - 1]);
    arr.shift();
    a.play();
  }

}
```

либо, есть два массива: один со звуками, другой с индексами этих звуков в рандомном порядке. при при использовании звука, его индекс нужно удалить из массива:

```js
function() {

  let arr = [3, 1, 2];
  let sound = ["sound1.mp3", "sound2.mp3", "sound3.mp3"];
  let audio = new Audio(sound);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let a = new Audio(sound[arr[i] - 1]);
    arr.shift();
    a.play();
  }
```

запуск звука по одному, по клику, как его сделать я знаю. объясните пожалуйста как быть

Comment: Так в чем именно проблема?

Comment: проблема решена. теперь проблема нахождение индекса массива без цикла и жесткой привязки к элементу. может, есть идея как это делать?

Comment: У меня есть идея! Расскажите нам, что вы хотите сделать. Постарайтесь описать это максимально подробно.

Comment: уже решила проблему :) спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [3, 1, 2];
let sound = ["sound1.mp3", "sound2.mp3", "sound3.mp3"];

function fn() {
  let a = new Audio(sound[arr[0] - 1]);
  a.play();
}
```

Здесь происходит определение правильности звука и удаление уже прозвучавшего:

```js
function onClick(event) {
  if (index.sound == vaule.выбора) {
    arr.shift();
    fn();
  } else {
    arr.shift();
    fn();
  }
  if (arr.length == 0) {
    console.log("finish");
  }
```